# Logging over MQ

Tags: c++, logging, mq

I am developing a game server, of course I need to implement logs to debug it in cases of crash.
As far I documented myself, there are three different ways to do it :
- logging on the console,
- logging in a file,
- logging over the network,

I am particularly interested in the last one, and more specifically using MQ for logging info.

What I actually would like to do is to have my server communicate via MQ to another server which host an elastic search/kibana/logstash that will aggregate logs and make it easy to explore.

But is it worth it in terms of performance ?
My question is : Is it fast enough for a game development to use MQ for logging purpose ?

Comment: While you may use Elasticsearch to aggregate the data, it's not really relevant to the question and so should not be added as a tag.

Comment: As for your question, if you go for an "industrial-grade" MQ then many of those are used in really big and data-heavy systems where large amounts of data are transmitted thousands or maybe even tens of thousands of times per second.

Comment: I removed the elastic tag. Thank you for your answer, I knew mq was a great way to communicate. I just couldn't really tell what was the impact for the caller. From your answer it appears it isn't a bad idea to use mq to do the log of my server. Thank you